# Is it possible to deploy BHO using Click Once deployment

Tags: clickonce, bho

Is it possible to use the Click Once technology in order to deploy Browser Helper Objects(BHO)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Browser Helper Objects require an addition of a key to the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

part of the registry. They may also be required to be installed under the Windows or Program Files directory.

ClickOnce runs in a sandbox, hence why it is allowed to install on a machine where admin rights and not available. This sandbox prevents access to either the registry or the system directories (outside of the user profile).

So for the case of Browser Helper Objects I think it is highly unlikely that you could use ClickOnce to deploy one.